# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop mouse freezes after going back from suspend

Tags: unity, 16.04, mouse, suspend, touchpad

Under Ubuntu 16.04 PC AMD64 my laptop's mouse pointer freezes after coming back from suspend.  The mouse pointer won't respond to the mouse pad.  However, I tried attaching a USB mouse and its fine.  Seems like the touch pad of the laptop is disabled during/after the system suspend. I have tried numerous suggestions but nothing seems to work.  Anyone out there know's how to go around this bug?